# Issue With .next_month in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date, ruby-1.9

In my local enviroment everything works fine.  When I upload to my server, I keep getting an Internal Server Error. I've commented out my code until I found the offending line which is:

```
 dateObj = dateObj.next_month #Problem Child
```

Here is the complete code:

```
def makeCal(dateObj)
    cal = Hash.new
    months = 0
    while months < 12
    #   #pass dateobj to build array
      array = buildArray(dateObj)
    #   #save array to hash with month key
      monthName = Date::MONTHNAMES[dateObj.mon]
      cal[monthName] = array
    #   #create new date object using month and set it to the first
      date = dateObj.month.to_s +  '/' + 1.to_s + '/' + dateObj.year.to_s
      dateObj = Date.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
      puts dateObj.kind_of? Date
      dateObj = dateObj.next_month #Problem Child
      months = months + 1
    end
    cal

  end
```

And ruby -v locally:

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

and ruby -v remotely:

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**UPDATE:**

173.26.190.206 - - [03/Sep/2011 10:40:17] "POST /calendar " 500 30 0.0020

That's from nginx

and this is the stack trace:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `next_month' for #<Date: 4911549/2,0,2299161>:
./main.rb:82:in `makeCal'
./main.rb:120:in `POST /calendar'
```

I inserted the line: puts dateObj.kind_of? Date

and I get all true. So my dateObj is of kind Date

Comment: `Internal Server Error`: no more details?

Comment: Yeah, try to get a stack trace.  There might be one in one of your log files.  If not, you could surround this function with a rescue clause and print the stack trace in the HTML page.

Comment: @Mladen I tried that. It didn't work. The once your require date you should be able to operate on it like I've done. I believe it's being created incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you lack

```
require 'active_support'
```

BTW, if all you need from it is `next_month`, you can use

```
date_obj >>= 1
```

as `Date#>>` is part of core library.

Edit:

For getting the first of the month, you can use:

```
Date.new(date_obj.year, date_obj.month)
```

Comment: I need the next month and the first day of that month.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that `next_month` is in the corelib as well, it should work well. The only explanation I have is that some gem undefined it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you have any idea how I can hunt this down or rewrite the code? Date doesn't have a setter method that I'm aware of that I can just set the day.

Comment: If it is working on your local machine, and not on the server, I would check which gems differ. Re: the day, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks. I loaded main.rb into my IRB and manipulated it manually the same way my code does and it throws up the same error. But locally it runs just fine. This is really odd. I'm going to mess around with your Date.new and see if I can figure out a way to do it that way.

Comment: What does date_obj >>= 1 do exactly? It fixed this problem but now my months are out of order. I'm using a hash, which in 1.9.2 is ordered. Would this be effecting that?

Comment: It is a shorthand for `date_obj = date_obj >> 1`, and `>>` is explained here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000393. I don't think it is affecting ordering as it is working the same as `next_month` (Actually, `next_month` is defined using `>>`).